# Perl LDAP Search - To return total number of people from an LDAP group

Tags: perl, ldap

I am trying to find the total number of people present in an LDAP group. Can you please help me in getting the count from the LDAP group(based on the DN) using [Net::LDAP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::LDAP) in Perl?

Also, can you please suggest what could be the filter to be applied to get the number of people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed and explained as your question ;)

```
use strict;
use Net::LDAP;
my $ldap = Net::LDAP->new($LDAP_HOST);

my $result = $ldap->search(
    base   => $DN_OF_THE_GROUP,
    filter => '(objectclass=*)',
    attrs  => ['member']
);

if ($result->code) {
    die $result->error;
}

my $entry = $result->entry;
my @members = $entry->get('member');
print scalar @members, "\n"
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I'm no expert at all in perl. Just edited it ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Can you please tell me if there is a way to find the group_dn (along with the count) , that has least number of people in it among the input list of groups?